# Handling PayPal IPN on database connection error

Tags: php, paypal

I'm having issues with PayPal IPN marking some payments as sent (HTTP 200 OK) even when MySQL Connection to the database is failing. How would I fix this - could I return maybe a `403` or something instead so PayPal will retry it?

Comment: please post your code

Comment: It's simple. PayPal sends a IPN. If MySQL is unable to connect PayPal will mark it as sent even though the script was not executed correctly.

Comment: @JohnJoe is trying to help you Path, post your code so he can help.

Comment: I understand, but I don't understand why the code is necessary to help me out with or die(send HTTP status code)

Answer (score 0):

It does appear that PayPal uses the 200 return code to confirm successful receipt, and will try again if this is not satisfied.

> If your server fails to respond with a successful HTTP response (200), PayPal will resend this IPN either until a success is received or up to 16 times.

Source: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/

Comment: Yes. But if there's a MySQL connection failed, it will still send a 200 OK even though the entry wasn't added to the database :-)

Comment: If output has not begun (nothing yet printed and no whitespace before your PHP tag) you can specify the return code with, for example `http_response_code(500)`